How to find out the fps of a video stream/ffmpeg?
console.log(this.dsh.getBitrateInfoListFor('video'))


I use this:

https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html

How can I find out the FPS of a video stream?
To do this, do I need to specify a parameter during conversion that will fit into the video manifest?
How do I do this, write it in the FFmpeg command?

Do you have ffprobe?

It is necessary to extract fps from the video stream via javascript

How can I specify fps in the manifest for each video stream during conversion...
